# Virasoro constraint under the static gauge

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, gauge

I am reading an article on introduction to string theory.

Consider an open string of length $L$, rotating around its center of mass with angular velocity $\omega$. Here we fix the gauge by the static gauge $\eta_\mu X^\mu = \tau$, where $\eta_\mu= (1,0,\cdots, 0)$. It claims that,

> "under the static gauge, the time-dependent and space-dependent part of the Virasoro constraint decouple, so we can write the constraint as an equation only dependent of the spatial part:
> $$
> (\dot{X}\pm X')^2 = 1."
> $$

I thought the above equation is the Virasoro constraint, but why it changed from
$$
(\dot{X}\pm X')^2 = 0
$$
to the above equation by applying the static gauge? Or if I misunderstood the text.

Comment: Which article? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic The original text is not in English. I translated the text myself here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations of motion are
$$
T_{ab} = \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X_\mu - \frac{1}{2} \gamma_{ab} \gamma^{cd} \partial_c X^\mu \partial_d X_\mu  = 0 . 
$$
Working this out in $(\tau,\sigma)$ coordinates, we get
$$
T_{\tau\tau} = T_{\sigma\sigma} = \frac{1}{2} [ {\dot X}^\mu {\dot X}_\mu + X'^\mu X'_\mu ] = 0 , \qquad T_{\tau\sigma} = {\dot X}^\mu X'_\mu .  
$$
These equations together imply
$$
( {\dot X}^\mu \pm X'^\mu ) ( {\dot X}_\mu \pm X'_\mu ) = 0 .
$$
Then using the gauge $X^0 = \tau$, we find
$$
| \dot{\vec{X}} \pm \vec{X}'|^2 = ( {\dot X}^0 \pm X'^0 )^2 = 1 .
$$

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the last line. By $\vec{X}$'s, did you mean $X^\mu$'s, where $\mu\neq 0$? Also, I don't get the equalities. Could you elaborate on that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course. That is standard notation. $\vec{X} = (X^1,\cdots,X^{D-1})$.